# Getting an uploaded file into home directory with proper ownership and permissions

Tags: php, linux, apache

I'm working on an upload script for students in my lab class to upload their assignments to a folder inside my home directory. The problem is that the script is run under the user apache and any directories and files created by the script end up owned by that user.  In addition the permissions of the folder I wish the files to end up in have to be set wide open so that apache can create directories and move files into it (which of course will still be owned by apache).

I'm trying to replace an old script provided by the department which, among other problems, has about 5 different use cases where the student can receive a confirmation when the file wasn't actually uploaded.  That script does use `chown` apparently without any of the problems PHP has.  Perhaps the python interpreter runs with different access setting that the PHP one does.

What tactics are there for handling this?

Comment: It's possible that the server settings prevent apache from changing permissions to a certain level or changing ownership.  You may be able to update these with your own server configuration or other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways to cope with this, but the most benign that I can imagine is to dedicated a sub-directory in your home directory for the purpose of uploading assignments.

All you have to do permissions wise is give the directory group ownership by some group the apache user belongs to.  Suppose the webserver user is **apache**, and furthermore there is a group **apache** said user is a member of.  You could also create a common group for this purpose that you and apache are part of.

Now let's say the directory you want to put the uploaded files in is **~/homework-submissions**

As yourself

```
mkdir ~/homework-submissions
chgrp apache ~/homework-submissions
chmod g+a ~/homework-submissions
```

With this arrangement in place newly created files will be owned by apache:apache, but the webserver should have no problem changing ownership at this point.